# Android HttpURLConnection xml encoding

Tags: android, xml, utf-8

I am trying to send XML data with POST request to the server. But getting 500 error.

```
URL url = new URL(AFConstants.ServerEndPoint);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/xml;charset=utf-8");
            http.setDoOutput(true);
            http.setDoInput(true);
            http.connect();
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(http.getOutputStream());
            String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(xml,"UTF-8");
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(encoded);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

String xml contains this:

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8"?>
<AddSalesOrder revision=“8.0” environment=“Production” lang=“en-US” xmlns:xsi=“http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance” xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=“C:\Data2\Ntp\shoprvparts\AddSalesOrder.xsd”>
    <ApplicationArea>
        ...
    </ApplicationArea>
    <DataArea>
        <Add confirm=“Always”/>
        <SalesOrder>
            <Header>

            </Header>
            <Line>
    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
    <OrderItem>
        ...
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderQuantity uom=“string”></OrderQuantity>
</Line>
        </SalesOrder>
    </DataArea>
</AddSalesOrder>
```

Comment: 500 error means server error. Ask the one who developed the server.

Comment: @VladMatvienko impossible. only have iOS (objective-C)code where this works OK.

Comment: it does not matter. You have to ask the backend developers why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

500 Internal Server Error or HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error

Cause of HTTP 500 Errors
Most of the time, "wrong" means an issue with the page or site's programming, but there's certainly a chance that the problem is on your end
 so i think there will be error logs on the server and if you have access you can provide the server logs and will be easy to identify the problem

Comment: response also contains message  "Invalid file". so i this it`s because of wrong encoding from my side.